# How to get field name in json

Tags: php, json

i have json data , lets say like this

```
$string='[{"main_menu_id":"1","main_menu_caption":"Home","main_is_get_from_page":"0","is_sub_menu":"0","main_url_page":"","sub_menu_caption":"","caption_type":"","sub_is_get_from_page":"","sub_url_page":"","sub_additional_param":""}]';
```

how to get field name only in this json data?
the result that i expected is main_menu_id, Main_menu_caption, etc. i need to extract keyname not value

Comment: What does that mean? What do you expect the result to be? What have you tried and what did you find difficult doing it?

Comment: YOu mean to get the key name like main_menu_id or main_menu_caption

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: Call `decode_json()`, then it's ordinary PHP data that you can process using functions like `array_keys()`.

Comment: @NullPonyPointer nice comment, could see it in most of the recent questions! ;-)

Comment: And what problem did you have applying `json_decode()` and `array_keys()`?

Comment: Sorry no way to post answer now :P You can decode the json using json_decode and use array_keys to get all the keys of the array. You can do like this
      $decoded_json = json_decode($string, true);
    
    $keys = array_keys($decoded_json[0])
    print_r($keys);


Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string='[{"main_menu_id":"1","main_menu_caption":"Home","main_is_get_from_page":"0","is_sub_menu":"0","main_url_page":"","sub_menu_caption":"","caption_type":"","sub_is_get_from_page":"","sub_url_page":"","sub_additional_param":""}]';
$arrJson  = array();
$arrJson  = json_decode($string);
foreach($arrJson as $key=>$value){
  foreach($value as $keyval=>$val){
    echo $keyval."<br>";
  }
}
```

Comment: result is that i need, but why it looping to other record too, (my string is sample but real record more than that) thanks

Comment: @Roro No need to loop use array_keys that will be much easier rather than  a for each loop

Comment: What if a multi dimenional array comes???

Comment: If you get the desired output mark it as correct answer

Comment: i newbie in php, i need to parse fieldname as your result to be header for my own table, and the value is as row table

Comment: @Deepu Your method is good and correct but to be easier, there is no need to two foreach then, use one for each and then use anonymous function to  get the output. Will be much faster and will reduce the code

Comment: @sabari, can you show me the example, sory my php still bad

Comment: @sabari,Its a object array and how do you get the keys of array using array_keys???

Comment: @Roro $decoded_json = json_decode($string, true);

$keys = array_keys($decoded_json[0]);

array_walk($keys, function ($a) {echo $a;});

Comment: @Deepu the second parameter in json_decode I have passed (json_decode($string, true);) will convert object array in to associative arrays